# Merge cells using vba based on a value

Tags: vba, excel

I have columns J through X in my excel spreadsheet with the following values:

```
J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X
1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3
```

Where the values are variables themselves and can change.  For example the values can also be:

```
J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X
1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
```

I am trying to write a vba that will merge all cells (to the right) with values 1, 2, 3, etc.  Any help would be appreciated.

The result for example 1 would be:  Columns J through N would have merged as 1.  Columns O through U would have merged as 2.  Columns V through X would merge to 3.  See below

```
J                   O                           V       
1                   2                           3
```

Thank you.

I found an answer elsewhere.  I'll leave it here in case anyone is interested

```
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim rngMerge As Range, cell As Range
    Set rngMerge = Range("J5:X5") 'Set the range limits here

MergeAgain:
    For Each cell In rngMerge
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 1)).Merge
            GoTo MergeAgain
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: In column Y are you looking for something like `111112222222333` for the 1st example and `122222223333333` for the 2nd?

Comment: I'd want columns J through N as 1, O through U as 2 and V through X as 3 for the first example.

Comment: What is the required output?

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I answered my question.  In case anyone is interested.

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim rngMerge As Range, cell As Range
    Set rngMerge = Range("J5:X5") 'Set the range limits here

MergeAgain:
    For Each cell In rngMerge
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 1)).Merge
            GoTo MergeAgain
        End If
    Next
```